# jQuery change id!

Tags: jquery, css

I am a jQuery noobie, and have been trying to add a script to change the id of a div onClick.

Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/475ep/).

```
$(function accept() {
    $("div:scrollwrap").attr('scrollwrap','highlight');
});​
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first parameter of `attr` should be the attribute name, not the current value:

```
$(function accept() {
    $("div#scrollwrap").attr('id','highlight');
});​
```

However, reading your jsFiddle code, you appear to have a class of highlight and not an ID. [Here is my edited version](http://jsfiddle.net/dZQ3P/1/) with what I think you are trying to achieve.

Note that I have changed the following:

- Made the .hightlight class more specific by adding the ID, otherwise the highlight style will not override the original.
- Removed the inline onClick as you can do this within your script, which is considered best practice (see JS for the `.click()` addition)
- Changed the JS function to toggle the class, as I assume it should be invalidated if the user deselects the checkbox.

More resources (jQuery docs):

- [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)
- [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
- [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to change the div with the id scrollwrap to have the id highlight:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#checkbox2").click(function() {
        $("#scrollwrap").attr('id','highlight');
    });
 });
```

remember an ID is unique, so this should only affect one element. if you want to affect multiple use classes and the functions .addClass()/.removeClass()

Comment: Thanks, that worked, how do I add it to my onCLick function? `<input value="1"  type="checkbox" name="salgsvilkar" ID="checkbox2"  onclick="accept();" />`

Answer (score 1):

this is how you change a ID:

```
$(function accept(){ //makes sure your document is ready
  $('div#scrollwrap').attr('id', 'highlight')
})
```

(i assume scrollwram is you ID)