# changing id of div using jquery

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

**EDIT 2:** Problem solved. The jquery pluggin created a div. I was barking up the wrong tree.
Thanks for all your swift answers! long time reader of stackoverflow but first time i've posted a question!

**EDIT**: So the reason why I want to change the id is to change the rating of a rating bar(I use the jrating jquery pluggin). The pluggin uses the digits in the beginning of the id to set the initial rating. Now I want to use ajax when I load a new player and that new player has a new rating that I want to update. Is this enough context?

Im at a loss here. I want to change the `id` of a selected `div` but it doesnt work!
I does seem to change the `div id` because `document.title` has the correct `id` when I give it the `id` of the `div` I just changed. However When I open the source code of my webpage the `id` didnt change...

```
function changePlayer() {
    xmlhttp = createXHR();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        document.title = "onreadystatechange";
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.title = "4 and 200 is ok!";
            var xmlDocument = xmlhttp.responseXML;
            var playerId = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            var playerName = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("firstName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            var playerlastName = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("lastName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            var playerTeamId = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("teamId")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            var playerPicUrl = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("mainPic")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            var playerShooting = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("shooting")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            document.getElementById("playerNameAndTeam").innerHTML = "<b>" + playerName + " " + playerlastName + "</b>" + "<br>" + playerTeamId;
            document.getElementById("playerPicture").src = "img/players/" + playerPicUrl;
            $("[id*='_shooting']").attr("id", playerShooting / 10 + "_shooting"); //attr("id", "5.1_shooting");
            document.title = $("[id*='_shooting']").attr("id");
            $("[id*='_shooting']").css("background-color", "blue");
            $("[id*='playerNameA']").css("background-color", "blue");
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "playerPageMVC/AJAX/getInfoPlayer.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function createXHR() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you meen with checking the source code? Are you using something like firebug or "inspect element" in Chrome?

Comment: You mean like you click 'view source code' and the ID is still the same? You can't change that source code with Javascript.

Comment: Good question indeed (if you do "View source code" you will see the original code naturally :). Also .attr() works just fine replacing ID (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712095/jquery-change-id) so you will have to provide some more details as I can't really see a problem here.

Comment: @putvande yes thats what I did. Why can't I change that source code?

Comment: Because the source code you view is generated by the server and send back to the client. Javascript can only change things client side and therefore can't change the source code. Why do you want this?

Answer (score 2):

Try with Native JS like replacing this line :

```
$("[id*='_shooting']").attr("id",playerShooting/10 + "_shooting");
```

By this one :

```
$("[id*='_shooting']")[0].id = playerShooting/10 + "_shooting";
```

Caution : If `$("[id*='_shooting']")` match many elements, only the first will be changed.

EDIT : If you want to keep jQuery technic, depends on your version, you can try using `prop(...)` instead of `attr(...)`

Answer (score 1):

when I tried changing ID with a sample code using JQuery it worked. You can view example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SsLmN/). Just change the `id attribute`

**You are suppose to check the id change by inspecting element not by checking the loaded source of the web page**.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean your:

```
$("[id*='_shooting']").attr("id", playerShooting / 10 + "_shooting");
```

You can check that id by simply doing these:

```
$("[id*='_shooting']").attr("id", playerShooting / 10 + "_shooting");
alert($("#"+ playerShooting / 10 + "_shooting").attr("id"));
```

By viewing the source, you only view the original source, not the DOM as it exists in a current state.